# Why do people leave out the "r" on the word your?

Tags: orthography

I have noticed that a common error in typed documents (Including my own) is that often the letter "r" is left off the word your.

Does anybody have any idea why?

I do note that sometimes when proofing a sentence I've just typed I notice this, and typing it has been recent enough that I can "play back" what I've just done in my head and I find I am pretty sure I have actually left the "r" out rather than it being a keyboard mis-strike...

Comment: Can you give an example sentence? That would make it more concrete.

Comment: Has it occurred to you that Kiwis rarely sound the "r" in "your"? I have no problem typing the "r", possibly because I almost growl it. I do misspell other words, though.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the letter being an "r", @J.Taylor. My English is non-rhotic, like the majority of people from England; but I do not pronounce "you" and "your" the same.

Comment: @Colin Fine....of course "you" and "your" are not pronounced the same. The quality of the vowel (or sonnet) in the word does change in :"your". That, to accommodate the loss of the final "growl" (r). .

Comment: The faster I type, the more mistakes I make.  And "you" instead of "your" seems a likely mistake a typist may make.  Plus, it will not be caught by spell-checkers.  Whereas **my** most likely mistake, "hte" instead of "the", **is** caught by spell-checkers.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the human brain substitutes words if you're not focused.  The brain thinks 'Oh, I know what word to use.' when it really doesn't and should listen to your conscious mind.

For example, when I was typing this response just now, I typed '...if your not focused." even though I know that's wrong.  It was just the habit of writing certain words.

This is also why a person should proofread his or her work backwards, because if he or she proofreads forwards, the brain will frequently substitute what it knows should be there (a correctly spelled word) instead of what is actually there (a typo).